# Mapnik TextSymbolizer value as integer

Tags: shapefile, mapnik

I'm working with [TextSymbolizer](http://mapnik.org/docs/v2.0.2/api/python/mapnik._mapnik.TextSymbolizer-class.html) in [Mapnik](http://mapnik.org/). I have a shapefile with a attribute which is a **real**. I wish to print the value of this attribute as **integer** and I don't find how I can do it in Mapnik.

I must not change the source shapefile. Can someone advise of the recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Not having found a solution to do exactly what I want, I bypassed the problem using a regular expression. If the real attribute is 'VAL' and the decimal separator is '.':

```
<TextSymbolizer placement = "line" fontset-name = "fontset-0" size = "11" dy = "-4" halo-fill = "rgba (255, 255, 255, 0.5)" halo-radius = "1" > 
<! [CDATA [[VAL]. replace ('\. [0-9] +','')]]>
</ TextSymbolizer>
```

Comment: I did not have to use the CDATA, and changed the expression to `[VAL].replace ('\.[0-9]+','')`. Other than that, great solution!